# Javascript: Creating Custom Functions which look like the Default ones

Tags: javascript, function, coding-style, default

When I want to create and use a function what accepts another function in it as an argument I usually do:

```
// Create Function
function doSomething(func){
    func();
}

// Call Function
doSomething(function(){
   ...
});
```

but in javascript(and many other languages what I know) there a default functions such as `if`, `while`, `for`, `function` where there is a different format when I call them:

```
while(i < 10){
    ...
}
```

So this `while` function doesn't have another "parent" function. Is it possible to make my own functions in this style in javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this as they are inbuilt language constructs. You can of course have a function in your global scope but they work just as any other function would.

Answer (score 1):

You can't -- `while` isn't a function, it's a reserved keyword that is parsed out by the javascript engine.  If you made a function and called it:

```
myFunc(i < 10){ ... }
```

you would just end up with `myFunc(true)` or `myFunc(false)`

And the extra `{` and `}` would be syntax errors.